# working typescript code in VS Code is underlined on red

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I cloned a repo with React app which works well when running on localhost but the files with .ts and .tsx code are full of red underlines even though there are no errors in the console. How to fix it? I tried to change TypeScript version in VS Code as it was suggested as a solution for the problem but there is only one to choose. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Comment: Did you try hovering over one of the lines to see what the reported error is?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes. For example for import it is something like: invalid module name in augmentation, MODULE-NAME module cannot be found. But it is found and it is working.

Comment: Have you restarting VSCode, and if that didn't work, restarting your computer?

Comment: Samathingamajig, actually yes, but it did not help.

Comment: You've cloned a repo, but have you ran `npm install` to install the packages? They don't come with the repo because `node_modules` can be a huge folder (that's why we use `package.json`)

Comment: I installed packages with docker.

Comment: you need to install them on your local dev machine to be able to use the types in VSCode, docker runs its own containerized operating system

Comment: I just runned npm install and the result printed was "up to date in 0.606s found 0 vulnerabilities". And it didn't help.